# Scatter plot legend icons are blank when using `FastLineAndPointRenderer`

Tags: androidplot

When I use a regular `LineAndPointRenderer`, all my legend icons appear normally.

```
//works but is slow
private LineAndPointFormatter getScatterPlotFormatter() {
    LineAndPointFormatter formatter = new LineAndPointFormatter(
            Color.TRANSPARENT,
            Color.argb(0xFF, mRandom.nextInt(0xFF), mRandom.nextInt(0xFF), mRandom.nextInt(0xFF)),
            null,
            null
    );
    formatter.getVertexPaint().setStrokeWidth(getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chart_vertex_size));
    return formatter;
}
```

[image: legend working correctly]

The [documentation](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/xyplot.md#user-content-lineandpointrenderer) suggests I use a `FastLineAndPointRenderer` instead, but when I do, the legend icons appear blank. This only affects my scatter plots.

```
//does not show proper legend icon
private LineAndPointFormatter getScatterPlotFormatter() {
    FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter formatter = new FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter(
            Color.TRANSPARENT,
            Color.argb(0xFF, mRandom.nextInt(0xFF), mRandom.nextInt(0xFF), mRandom.nextInt(0xFF)),
            null
    );
    formatter.getVertexPaint().setStrokeWidth(getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chart_vertex_size));
    return formatter;
}
```

[image: missing legend icon]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed some easier way to do this. If so, please post another answer. Otherwise, extending the class and adding the code to paint the vertex canvas worked for me:

```
public static class FastScatterChartRenderer extends FastLineAndPointRenderer {
    public FastScatterChartRenderer(XYPlot plot) {
        super(plot);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDrawLegendIcon(Canvas canvas,
                                    RectF rect,
                                    Formatter formatter) {
        super.doDrawLegendIcon(canvas, rect, formatter);
        if(formatter.hasVertexPaint()) {
            canvas.drawPoint(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), formatter.getVertexPaint());
        }
    }
}

@NonNull
private LineAndPointFormatter getScatterPlotFormatter() {
    FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter formatter = new FastLineAndPointRenderer.Formatter(
            null,
            Color.argb(0xFF, mRandom.nextInt(0xFF), mRandom.nextInt(0xFF), mRandom.nextInt(0xFF)),
            null
    ){
        @Override
        public Class<? extends SeriesRenderer> getRendererClass() {
            return FastScatterChartRenderer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public SeriesRenderer doGetRendererInstance(XYPlot plot) {
            return new FastScatterChartRenderer(plot);
        }
    };
    formatter.getVertexPaint().setStrokeWidth(getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chart_vertex_size));
    return formatter;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `FastLineAndPointRenderer` implementation.  I created [this report](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/issues/39) to track it - will be fixed in the next release.  Your approach above looks like a good solution in the interim.